# Split text string in Excel by semicolons and space

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Supposedly I have an excel column which looks like this:
[image]

How do I achieve this using excel formula:
[image]

Right now, I am able to retrieve these using:
[image]

`=LEFT(D2,SEARCH(";",D2,1)-1)` (First)

`=MID(D2, SEARCH(";",D2) + 1, SEARCH(";",D2,SEARCH(";",D2)+1)-SEARCH(";",D2)-1)` (Second)

`=RIGHT(D2,SEARCH(";",D2,1)-1)` (Third)

I'd realised that the text was cut off for the `RIGHT` formula. How can I separate the text using `CHAR(10)` when each semicolon is found?

Comment: Do you want a `VBA` or formula solution? Your question asks for a formula but you have iused the `vba` tag

Comment: What is the logic behind the 3th line in your desired result (SAMPLE; SAMPLE)? Rest of the strings is delimited per semicolon.

Comment: How about column to string option. That is already built in.

Comment: @JvdV , it is supposed to retrieve (SAMPLE; SAMPLE SENTENCE) instead of (E.SENTENCE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the semi-colon and space with a semi-colon and new line character.

Use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"; ", ";" & CHAR(10))` and ensure the cell has text wrapping on.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Data from the main menu then click on Text to Columns. Choose the option delimited and tick the semicolon  option. Follow the wizard and you'll get your data formatted as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use

```
split()
```

to split your cell value by ";" and

```
trim()
```

to cut off additional spaces.